# User descriptions missing when OpenLDAP used with WebLogic

Tags: weblogic12c, openldap

I am using a WebLogic 12.2.1.3 server on Linux. I added an OpenLDAP provider in the security realm. Now I see the list of users and group memberships in WebLogic as defined in LDAP and can login with one of those user cn's and password.

So far, so good.

However, in the Users and Groups list, the description column is blank for the LDAP entries. Which attribute should be added to the LDAP object to fill this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is just named "description" for me

Comment: Duh! Pardon me while I go screw my head on in the right direction. Thanks.